How do I move to MyFaces from Mojarra on WildFly 31.0.1.Final?
I have in the past tried to install & run MyFaces on WildFly instead of Mojarra with little success.
I read an article from Jason Lee "Coming Up for Air" using "Galleon Provisioning" see "MyFaces 4 on WildFly":
With Jakarta EE 10.0.0. I tried using 'Galleon':
/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/galleon-5.2.2.Final/bin/galleon.sh install \
       org.wildfly:wildfly-myfaces-feature-pack:2.0.0.Final \
       --dir=wildfly-31.0.1.Final \
       --config=standalone.xml \
       --layers=myfaces

Feature pack installed.d. 

Shows:
grep myfaces wildfly-preview-31.0.1.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.1" default-jsf-impl-slot="myfaces"/>

WildFly 31.0.1.Final shows:
WARN  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJSF0005: Unknown Jakarta Server Faces version 'myfaces-4.0.2'.  Default version 'main' will be used instead.
WARN  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJSF0005: Unknown Jakarta Server Faces version 'myfaces-4.0.2'.  Default version 'main' will be used instead.

INFO  [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Initializing Mojarra 4.0.5 for context '/BeWhereWhen'

Anyone managed to install MyFaces on WildFly using Galleon?
I'm always seem to be using 'Mojarra"! TIA.
I'm currently using:

WildFly Distribution 31.0.1.Final & 32.0.0.Beta1
--server-config=standalone.xml
openjdk version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16
Jakarta EE 10.0.0 & 11.0.0-M2
Gradle 8.7
macOS Sonoma 14.4.1


I'm not sure about using preview as it is for JakartaEE 11, why not use simply WF 31 or 32 ?

I'm using Jakarta EE 10.0.0. Have to use WildFly Preview Distribution since Jakarata. Using WildFly Distribution (22.x  EE9 ->) as my EAR won't deploy with: ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."BeWhereWhen.ear"."BeWhereWhenWAR.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."BeWhereWhen.ear"."BeWhereWhenWAR.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of  etc. etc.

Preview != EE10. Preview = "snapshot of next EE version". Since WildFly 27 the standard version is EE10 already. No need for Preview. It would represent snapshot of potential changes in EE11. Read the docs.

@BalusC Thank you for the clarification. I can only deploy my Jakarta App from WildFly 'Preview Distribution' 32.0.0.Beta1 & all down to "21.0.0.Final Jakarta EE Full & Web Distribution". If I use "WildFly Distribution" I get errors: "ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service" etc.

BTW - Removed 'implementation("net.bootsfaces:bootsfaces:1.5.0")' and allowed me to run on "--server-config=standalone.xml".
